# Specifying custom serializer for a relationship has_one json-api-rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonapi-rb

I have serializers:

```
class SerializableContact < JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource
  type :contacts

  has_one :email_event, class: 'SerializableEmailEvent' # class is not working
  has_many :geofence_notifications

  attributes :email,
             :order_id,
             :frequent_order_id
end

class SerializableEmailEvent < JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource
  ...
end
```

Models:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :email_event, -> { email }, class_name: 'Event'
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I am trying to make `SerializableContact` to use `SerializableEmailEvent` as the serializer for `email_event` relationship. But I cant figure out how to do that.  It always error out with:

```
JsonapiCompliable::Errors::MissingSerializer - Could not find serializer for class 'Event'!

Looked for 'SerializableEvent' but doesn't appear to exist.

Use a custom Inferrer if you'd like different lookup logic.
```

I am not sure how to use a custom inferrer for the different lookup logic

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am a bit late responding to your issue, but here you have how to do it:

```rb
has_one :email_event do
  linkage(always: true) do
    { type: "email_event", id: @object.email_event_id } if @object.email_event_id
  end
end
```

They *type* has to match with the type on your serilizable resource class. So I was expecting it to be:

```rb
class SerializableEmailEvent < JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource
  type "email_event"
  ...
end
```